# Data model reference using ObjectID in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have two mongoose models users and requests. One user can have multiple requests. To link these two data models, I am referencing the objectID of the user in the Request model. However when I am trying to fetch all the requests for a particular user ID, I don't get any result.

**Users**

```
    var UserSchema = new Schema({
      name: String,
      username: String
    });
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

**Requests**

```
var RequestSchema = new Schema({
  type: String,
  user_id: { type : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'}
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Request', RequestSchema);
```

Below is the sample code which fetches the requests based on the User ID passed in the URL

```
exports.getRequests = function (req, res, next) {
      var userId = req.params.id;
      console.log('USER ID'+userId);

      Request.findOne({'user_id': 'kenan'}, function (err, request) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!requests){
            console.log('NO REQUEST FOUND');
            return res.send(401);
        }
        res.json(request);
      });
};
```

I know I am using findOne which will return me a single resource. However this is failing and I am not getting any result. I have in my DB the data populated. Below is the URL for fetching the requests.

```
http://localhost:9000/api/V1/users/547ee1e82e47bb982e36e433/requests
```

Please help suggest as to what I am doing wrong over here.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [populate](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html) the references to the users once you do a `find()`.

- Once you find all the requests, you need to resolve the references to
  the users. Use populate to resolve the references.
- After resolving, filter the requests based on the `name` that you
  are searching for.

Updated Code:

```
Request
.find().populate({'path':'user_id',match:{'name':'kenan'}})
.exec(function (err, resp) {
  var result = resp.filter(function(i){
    return i.user_id != null;
  });
 console.log(result);
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will try this. However I am trying to find using Request.findOne(). Here also I need to use populate? My understanding was that populate should be used when I search the parent schema, in this case Users.

Comment: Populate is used to resolve references. In this case, your user_id needs to be resolved. Your schema design is perfect for a query to find all the users for a particular request type.

Comment: But I would like to find all the requests from a particular user_id. Why can't I just query the Request schema and specify the user_id just like any other column.

Comment: Short answer: No, because the findOne() or find() retrieve the records of the request collection first,without the references getting resolved. Explanation: When a field refers to a record in a different collection, the field contains the "_id" of the referred document and not the document itself. So the user_id would have the _id - `Object(....)` of the referred document and not the document `{name:...}`, if it had contained the document you could have queried it as a different column as you say, and that method is called `embedding` the referred document.

Comment: The populate feature of mongoose resolves the references, but after the find operation.

Comment: OK, thanks I understand that. In my case i want to query based on the _id of the referred document. Which should already be there in the Request document. The user_id field of the Request collection is referring to the _id field of the Users collection. Then why can't I query based on the user_id field?

Comment: You can query on the user_id field. But you should pass the _id of the user document and not the name field.

Comment: OK, I have modified my logic. However I am still not able to fetch the requests.                      Request.findOne({'user_id': userID}, function (err, request) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!requests){
            console.log('NO REQUEST FOUND');
            return res.send(401);
        }
        res.json(request);
      });

Answer (score 1):

OK, the above answer is correct and thanks for your response. I incorrectly populated my Requests collection. This is just for every one's else knowledge. When you have a Object ID reference as one of the fields in the collection then make sure that you are inserting the ObjectID object instead of just the numerical value.

**Wrong**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54803ae43b73bd8428269da3"), "user_id" : "547ee1e82e
47bb982e36e433", "name" : "Test", "service_type" : "test", "version" : "10"
, "environment" : "test", "status" : "OK", "__v" : 0 }
```

**Correct**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54803ae43b73bd8428269da3"), "user_id" : ObjectId("547ee1e82e
47bb982e36e433"), "name" : "test", "service_type" : "test", "version" : "10"
, "environment" : "test", "status" : "OK", "__v" : 0 }
```